# SVN location error

Tags: java, svn

I'm new to SVN
can some help me how to fix the below issue.

Location information has been specified incorrectly

> SVN :E175002 java.lang.numberformatException for input string: "ee"

[image]

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly you are doing. I assume you are running some java based frontend for SVN; that gives you an error message. So: which tool is that; what are you doing?!

Comment: This is a bug in Eclipse/Subversive. Check the linked thread.